# angular-cli generated project strict by default

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I created my project using angular-cli.  When I put the following in a .ts file

```
var a;
delete a;
```

error shows as "'delete' canot be called on an identifier in strict mode".
I'd like to know where is the strict mode being configured?

Answer (score 0):

In typescript2.1+, `--alwaysStrict` compiler option parses ts files in strict mode and emits "use strict" at the top of all outputted files. 
This is the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10758#issuecomment-250317007).